# Error 13 with Foundation when trying to run Grunt

Tags: gruntjs, zurb-foundation

> Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
>
> Warning: bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/functions:13: error: error reading >values after )
>   Use --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.

Look below for solution.

Comment: I would try grunt-contrib-sass instead, because of the notice on [grunt-sass' page](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass): `This task uses libsass which is an experimental Sass compiler in C++. In contrast to the original Ruby compiler, this one is much faster, but is missing some features`.  Also for anyone who cannot bother looking it up; Line 13 in scss/foundation/functions looks like this: `$modules: append($modules, $name) !global;`

Comment: I tried npm install -g grunt-contrib-sass and it didn't work... I had this same problem on another ubuntu system but got around it. Sadly, I can't remember how; I believe it was something with bower but I've installed bower globally and have ran bower install.

Answer (score 5):

So I found the solution to the error thanks to:

> Michael Degli-Angeli

(9/11/2014) - It appears Micheal removed his post from the following link/thread

http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/19063-grunt---error-error-reading-values-after----libsass

Turns out this is a error with Foundation and just started happening today. (9/10/2014)

---

**The Solution:**

Just remove !global from line 13 in

> bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/_functions.scss

and run grunt like so:

> ./node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt

**Note:** Be careful if your bower.json is compiling with the latest Foundation.

Comment: I also had this issue and removing `!global` fixed it. But why is `!global` there? What does it do? Will removing it cause other problems?

Comment: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/commit/8421ac43e9994b0f086c82630f05f2ee7be11d1f

It appears this is where a developer on foundation changed it. I guess !global works for Ruby Sass 3.3 but not with libsass. Removing it shouldn't affect anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The problem when removing !global is that I have now a very long compiled output file with a lot of dupped stuff. Just use the inspector in Chrome and you'll see... I can't find other solution for now...

Answer (score 0):

Simply updating grunt-sass seems to do the trick, see [Paul Angus's reply](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/19063-grunt---error-error-reading-values-after----libsass?page=2) on Zurb's forum

`npm install --save-dev grunt-sass`

Afterwards, `grunt build` *should* compile with no errors.